# Is there a way to insert an image/icon/shape inside a text in webflow?

Tags: webflow

Im new to webflow and fairly impressed with this website
https://aaply.app

Im building my portfolio on webflow and would like to recreate a hero section as seen here:

[image: images inside text block]

Is there a way to do so using webflow?

#21dayportfolio

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very simple.

First create a flex container on "horizontal".

Inside, put a first text block in "inline" display. Then add an image... It will fit in the text. Then add another text block still inline that will stick to the picture.

Have fun